# Form tag & date picker for entire datatables are not working

Tags: datatables

I have a datatable initialized as

```js
$("#grid").dataTable();
```

I have a form tag for the entire datatable as

```html
<form name="adddetails" id="adddetails" method="POST">
<table id="grid" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="30%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>S.No.</th>
<th>No. Of Jobs</th>
<th>Earliest Start Date</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tbodyy">
//there will be more than 30 records in my loop which i use to print in tbody. a ex of that is     below.
<tr>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;">1</td>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;"><input type="text" name="job" id="job"></td>
<td style="vertical-align: middle;"><input type="text" name="job" class="datepicker"  id="datepicker"></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

There are 2 problems i face here.

1. When i submit the form, only those text box values in page 1 of the grid is getting submitted. Skips all data from page 2
2. Date picker works for page 1 of the grid only. It doesn work from page 2.

I tried searching about this, but couldn find a solution.

Comment: Page 2 can't be submitted when it isn't displayed because the data simply doesn't exist in the form. [http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/185/submitting-forms-with-fields-on-hidden-pages](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/185/submitting-forms-with-fields-on-hidden-pages)

Comment: Is there anyway i could extend the form to all pages?

Comment: Not that I know of. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but from a user's perspective it sounds like a poor experience. Are you sure a datatable is the right solution?

Comment: I guess datatable is a right solution. Because i would like to maintain user interface all through my project.